# NUnit framework giving exception ' WebDriverManager.Clients.ChromeForTestingClient' after migrating Selenium-Webdriver 4.10 to 4.17 (C#)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

We are using Selenium-WebDriver+ C# +NUnit framework. Recently we have migrated Selenium-WebDriver 4.10 to 4.17.
When we try to executing the scripts in NUnit framework it giving following error.
We thoroughly verified all the driver, library locations all are loos good.
We are using Webdriver-manager.

Can someone please help me how to fix this issue.

Exception:

```
 Message: 
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'WebDriverManager.Clients.ChromeForTestingClient' threw an exception.
  ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13aacd2ffd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x90123131)
  ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13aacd2ffd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x90123131)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
ChromeForTestingClient.GetKnownGoodVersionsWithDownloads()
ChromeConfig.GetVersionFromChromeForTestingApi(String noRevisionVersion)
ChromeConfig.GetMatchingBrowserVersion()
DriverManager.GetVersionToDownload(IDriverConfig config, String version)
DriverManager.SetUpDriver(IDriverConfig config, String version, Architecture architecture)
```